# C2960 %LINEPROTO-5 UPDOWN and %LINK-3-UPDOWN when speed is not set on 100

Tags: cisco, layer1, cisco-2960

I have 4 ports.

3 are like this, Gi 0/1-3

```
switchport access vlan xxx
switchport mode access
power inline never
speed 100
spanning-tree portfast edge
```

One Trunk, Gi 0/8

```
switchport mode trunk
power inline never
```

Gi 0/2 keep disconnecting / reconnecting with tons of errors codes `%LINEPROTO-5 UPDOWN` and `%LINK-3-UPDOWN` if I remove the line `speed 100`

Why ?

Comment: What is in the log?  Also, what is plugged into the port?  Does it happen if you move devices around?

Comment: These 2 lines are the only lines in the log. They keep coming if I used 1000 instead of 100. If I change port, the new port create the same error. Gi 0/1 is computer with VNC Server, Gi 0/1 and 0/2 are both VNC client

Comment: Most likely, @Zac67 has the correct answer -- it's a cable problem

Comment: On a side note (now that the actual problem is solved): If ever, on this and similar product families by Cisco, I suggest to use `speed auto 100 10` instead of `speed 100`. It keeps speed & duplex negotiation intact while only offering 100 or 10 Mbits/sec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `speed 100` line configures the interface down to 100BASE-TX. If that works correctly and 1000BASE-T doesn't (the default, fully autonegotiated mode), the likely cause is a cable fault.

100BASE-TX and 10BASE-T use only two pairs of the four-pair cable. These pairs are also the ones used for autonegotiation. So, if one of the other pairs is at fault (or both), 1000BASE-T is still autonegotiated, but it can't complete the link due to the PCS sublayer failing to 'up' each lane/pair separately. This causes the port to fall back to autonegotiation, ad nauseam.

Some devices fall back to 100BASE-TX in such a case but that is not a given. Try a known-good cable.

Comment: We're going to change all the cable, I will make a feedback once it's done. Thank you !

Comment: And you were right. The cable were dead !